# Were there any other Edeljude pardoned by Hitler or high ranking Nazis?

Tags: nazi-germany

Alongside Eduard Bloch, were there any other known people of Jewish decent who were given the same sort of protection and pardon during the time in which the Nazi's were in power?

Comment: Are you aware of the [Honorary Aryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorary_Aryan) status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a few. The term for people of partially Jewish descent in Nazi Germany was *Mischling* and Wikipedia has [an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mischling) about them with a sampling of ones who were prominent, many of whom received the German Blood Certificate. The most notable example is [Erhard Milch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhard_Milch), a Luftwaffe Field Marshall.